# wordpress cufon not working

Tags: wordpress, plugins, cufon

I have just installed the cufon plugin for wordpress and am trying to get it to do a font replacement.

I have the following html:

```
<h2 class="gentium twelve columns"><?php echo get_bloginfo('description'); ?></h2>
```

And the following cufon css call:

```
Cufon.set('fontFamily', 'gentium-italic').replace('h2');
```

In the admin panel, the cufon plugin recognises the existence of "gentium-italic.js" and I get no javascript errors but the font isn't getting replaced on the front end.

Answer (score 0):

Open your Cufon-generated font file and check whether `font-family` name specified there matches the name you used in `Cufon.set()` function. The code you'll be looking for should look similar to:

```
Cufon.registerFont({"w":199,"face":{"font-family":"gentium-italic"...
```